# Launching Vim with a file as argument does not work, if my .vimrc contains a `:cd` command

Tags: windows, vim

If I launch Vim from powershell/cmd with a file (e.g `gvim myfile.txt`) it will open a empty buffer or if the file exist the wrong one. I tracked it down to the first line of my `.vimrc`

```
cd c:\myUsualFolder
```

If this line is removed everything works fine.

Does anyone has an idea how to keep the change directory part while opening the right file as well?

---

About my system: windows 10; vim version 8.0.586

Comment: If you don't find a solution here, you might also checkout https://vi.stackexchange.com/ or the vim mailing list.

Comment: If you want to be able to edit `c:\myUsualFolder\somefile` regardless of your current working directory I'd suggest you to replace the line `cd c:\myUsualFolder` in `~/.vimrc` with `set path+=c:\myUsualFolder`. To edit the file you could do `:find somefile`.

Comment: Have you try out the vim-command `:cd anyfolder` instead of a `cd anyfolder` in your config? With `:cd` you can change the "current working directory" of vim, always from _inside_ vim. (can checked with `:pwd`)